# How to get the PATH from .bashrc in JavaScript GitHub Action?

Tags: javascript, github, path, github-actions

This is a general problem with GitHub Actions and to have the `PATH` and other environment variables properly set up, we add the following to the top of our workflows:

```
defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash -leo pipefail {0}
```

That changes the shell that is used for commands so that it sources `.bashrc`. This is important to us, since we are using macOS runners and binaries installed with `brew` aren't in the default `PATH`. (There are also a few other reasons we need it.)

A colleague of mine has written a custom JavaScript action that executes a command that is in different locations on differnet runners, depending on OS and CPU architecture. To support all architectures, he's appending all locations to the `PATH` before executing the command:

```
PATH=$PATH:location1:location2 command
```

Another colleague of mine added a new runner type that installed the binaries to a third location. To be able to support the JavaScript action, he added symlinks to "location1" so that the command would be found by the action, without having to update the `PATH` in the action.

It's a bit of a mess and it could easily be cleaned up if I could get the JavaScript action to source `.bashrc` and have the proper `PATH` available. Only problem is that I don't know how to do that. It would be nice if there was some option I could pass to make it do that:

```
runs:
  using: 'node16'
  main: 'dist/index.js'
```

I could probably source `.bashrc` from within the JavaScript and I would accept such answers, as long it's not too messy.

Comment: Can you simply not set those custom `PATH`s using `core.addPath`? See [Using workflow commands to access toolkit functions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#using-workflow-commands-to-access-toolkit-functions) and https://github.com/actions/toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

The `.bashrc` file contains commands that are executed by **Bash**. It makes no sense to let **Node** do the work when **Bash** already can do it.

```
runs:
  using: 'node16'
  main: 'dist/index.js'
```

Any of such actions you can easily wrap as a composite action marking the javascript action `if: false` to not execute it (but it is still set up) and then execute it by the **node16** binary (`process.execPath` within any such action, export it) and execute the path to the file (it follows always the same pattern).

See this following example with placeholders what was invisible from the question:

```
runs:
  using: composite
  steps:
    - uses: <action-slug><path>@<ref> # node16 action
      if: 'false' # yes false
    - shell: bash
      run: |
        # do as it pleases yours with theirs environments
        source ./bashrc
        /home/runner/runners/2.304.0/externals/node16/bin/node \
          /home/runner/work/_actions/<action-slug>/<ref><path>/dist/index.js
```

`<path>` is empty for actions that are located in the repository root.

When the runner sets up the job, it will download the action repository revision (git clone):

```
Download action repository '<action-slug>@<ref>' (SHA:<of-rev>)
```

despite it has `if: false`.

This gives you the opportunity to run it in the next step *after* executing the `.bashrc` commands (or anything else pleases you to do with the environment).

If this is even already within a composite action and in the working tree, then even easier, as the path to the `index.js` file is already known and does need no other download action next to the checkout.